# Generating random numbers using SHA multiple times

Tags: random, sha, ab-testing, abtest

There were similar question on stackoverflow but not exactly mine.

So i have a sequence of numbers (from 1 to ~5,000,000) (call this number N). I want to map every number to a number from [0, 99]. One solution is to take the reminder of N divided by 100. All good. I again want to do this a second time and see to which number from [0, 99] this N gets mapped to. The only requirement is that the information that the N got mapped to a number from [0, 99] (say 34) the first time should not decide anything about the number it gets mapped to the second time.

So I want to do this (SHA(N + 1) % 100) on the first time and (SHA(N + 2) % 100) the second time and so on ..

Is it guaranteed to work ? or am i missing out something?

Simply put:
Take any two arbitrary numbers x1, x2 from [0, 99].
Count all numbers from [0, 5000000] which gets mapped to x1 the first time and x2 the second time. Is this count going to be the same (more or less) for any choice of x1,x2?

Answer (score 1):

I cranked out the results for 5 million values of `n`, `SHA1(N+1)%100`, and `SHA1(N+2)%100`, then ran it through a stats package.  The sets of SHA results were uniformly distributed between 0 and 99, and the correlation matrix was:

```
           n      sha+1    sha+2
    n   1.0000  -0.0016  -0.0016
sha+1  -0.0016   1.0000  -0.0001
sha+2  -0.0016  -0.0001   1.0000
```

In other words, the SHA outcomes are effectively uncorrelated with each other.  A given number 0-99 from the first SHA calculation is equally likely to be paired with any of 0-99 as the second SHA result across the set.

Comment: Thanks, I too have done  a similar test and am satisfied with the resuly